# If i have the binary data of an image inside a variable, how can i show it to the user into an html page (PHP)

Tags: php

im using the [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) libary to do some modifications to a image, when the proccess is done the binary data of the image is returned by `$new->output('jpg', 90);` The problem is that output is a binary data that i cant use with the `<IMG SRC="image.jpg">`. How can i adapt the code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just echo it out to the user when he requests the image.

This is the typical pattern:

```
<img src="image.php?image_id=23423">
```

This is what you do in the PHP

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $new->output('jpg', 90);
```